Bound from above and from below the probability that a 1-D centered random walk remains at each step inside a square root boundary
Let $W_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_i$ be a random walk on $\mathbb{R}$, where the increments $X_i$ are i.i.d., symmetric around the origin ($X\sim -X$), such that $-1\leq |X(\omega)| \leq 1$ $\forall\omega\in\Omega$, $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ and $Var(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2}$.
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $I_n$ be defined as:
$$
I_n = \bigcap_{k = 1}^{n} \Bigl[\frac{|W_k|}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 1\Bigr]
$$
I would like to find a function $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(n) > 0$ , $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n) = 0$ and
$$
P(I_{n-1})-P(I_n) \geq g(n)
$$
for all sufficiently large $n \geq n_0$.
Of course $P(I_{n-1})-P(I_n) \geq 0$ since $I_n\subseteq I_{n-1}$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(I_n) = 0$.
This question is intimately connected with this one: old question.
Also, I would like to better understand the connection between random walks on the real line and the brownian motion, since the replies to the other question use a lot this idea.
The title is referring to the fact that if we're able to bound from above and from below $P(I_n)$ then we can bound from above the expression we're interesting at.
I wonder if there are some famous inequalities I miss while researching similar stuff. Thank you in advance for any hint/advice!

Do you want $g$ to be independent of the distribution of $X_1$?

Not necessarily! If needed I can provide it. @IosifPinelis

You can provide what?

I mean, the distribution of $X_1$. I was not precise, sorry.

You can provide the distribution of $X_1$? In what sense?

In the sense that in my case $X_i = \cos{\theta_i}$ where $\theta_i$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi]$. Maybe it could be useful..

Doesn't then your question reduce to this: show that $P(I_{n-1})-P(I_n)>0$ for all large enough $n$?

Unfortunately my goal is to show that, in my case, the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(P(I_{n-1})-P(I_{n}))$ is divergent.. and in order to prove it I thought to bound that expression with a function $g(n)$ such that the series of $ng(n)$ is divergent. (If not, I otherwise have to show that the first series is convergent instead)

This goal should be, and should have been, stated explicitly in your post.

@MathRevenge Is the sum the same as something like $P(I_1) + \sum_{n = 1} P(I_n)$? (Write $n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1$, then use Tonelli's theorem to swap the sums.) That would imply you only need to bound $P(I_n)$ from below.
